# how to hide the "time" column in the table when use Grafana with influxes

Tags: grafana, influxdb

When I use table visualisation in Grafana with InfluxDB, the table panel always shows the `time` column, but I do not want it. So how can I achieve this?

I have searched similar questions on StackOverflow, but could not find any answer. My query does not include `time` as shown below:

```
"SELECT sum("load") AS "load" FROM "cpu" WHERE $timeFilter GROUP BY "host""
```

But the table panel looks as follows including the `time` column:

[image]

Answer (score 20):

This answer is for Grafana version 7.0.3 and later (previous versions 7.0.1 and 7.0.2 had related bugs which were fixed).

You can do this by adding the "Organize fields" transformation. Click "Transform" tab -> Click "Select" button on "Organize fields" row -> Click the "eye" icon on "Time" row.

Comment: This is the correct answer if you are using grafana v7.5.7

Answer (score 3):

You can hide the default `time` column using "Column Styles" in "Visualisation" tab. You must match the column name either by name or with a regex, and finally choose type "Hidden" as follows:

[image]

Comment: Is this option gone in v7??

Comment: @MikeKulls, did you find the solution in new version?

Comment: @BeliaevMaksim I did. It was actually so obvious I missed it. Next to query there is a tab named transform, you tick the columns on and off there

Comment: @MikeKulls, ou hell, I found it, thank you very much! Hidden under the nose :D